# No page other than home route (/) works directly or on reload on React App

Tags: reactjs

My react app is running fine in my localhost, but after building it, I can go to main route (/) only, but other routes do not work, getting 404.
I can go to those pages using navigate from main page, but attempt to reload or directly go to those pages does not work.
Please note, this issue does not happen while I'm running the app using npm start. I can share parts of my code, but not sure which parts to share.
I am using nginx as server.

Comment: Where are you hosting it?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was with the server.
I added this to my config file:

```
location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
  }
}
```